# My Sql query is very slow (60sec) , Any one have ideas to improve?

Tags: mysql, join, performance

My query is slow. I am searching between 3 tables. Se_movies = 80000 records , se_movie_contenttags=1.6 mil records , se_movie_descriptiontags -200000 records

two simplified queries.

**OR  - SLOW**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  count(movie_id)
FROM se_movies LEFT JOIN se_users ON se_movies.movie_user_id=se_users.user_id
LEFT  JOIN 
( 
  SELECT did , cid , ifnull(cid,did) as uid FROM ( SELECT tag_object_id AS did FROM se_movie_descriptiontags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS dtag
  LEFT  JOIN (SELECT tag_object_id AS cid FROM se_movie_contenttags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS ctag
  ON dtag.did=ctag.cid
UNION 
  SELECT did , cid , ifnull(cid,did) as uid  FROM ( SELECT tag_object_id AS did FROM se_movie_descriptiontags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS dtag
  RIGHT  JOIN (SELECT tag_object_id AS cid FROM se_movie_contenttags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS ctag
  ON dtag.did=ctag.cid
)
AS tagobjects ON se_movies.movie_id=tagobjects.uid
WHERE  ( se_movies.movie_title LIKE '%dog%') **OR**  (  (cid IS NOT NULL or  did IS NOT NULL) and uid IS NOT NULL )
```

**AND - Fast**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  count(movie_id)
FROM se_movies LEFT JOIN se_users ON se_movies.movie_user_id=se_users.user_id
LEFT  JOIN 
( 
  SELECT did , cid , ifnull(cid,did) as uid FROM ( SELECT tag_object_id AS did FROM se_movie_descriptiontags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS dtag
  LEFT  JOIN (SELECT tag_object_id AS cid FROM se_movie_contenttags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS ctag
  ON dtag.did=ctag.cid
UNION 
  SELECT did , cid , ifnull(cid,did) as uid  FROM ( SELECT tag_object_id AS did FROM se_movie_descriptiontags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS dtag
  RIGHT  JOIN (SELECT tag_object_id AS cid FROM se_movie_contenttags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog') ) AS ctag
  ON dtag.did=ctag.cid
)
AS tagobjects ON se_movies.movie_id=tagobjects.uid
WHERE   ( se_movies.movie_title LIKE '%dog%') **AND**  (  (cid IS NOT NULL or  did IS NOT NULL) and uid IS NOT NULL )
```

**each one alone**

```
( se_movies.movie_title LIKE '%dog%') - around 300
 (cid IS NOT NULL or  did IS NOT NULL) and uid IS NOT NULL - return 595
```

but it is fast if anyone of them return around 50 or less.

Basically if any keyword has above 500 in each tags and movie table title...it takes 60 sec

otherwise 2.3 sec.

is there a better way ?

i know u can do UNION between these two...
and AND for other stuff...

Search- title OR ( contenttag or desctag )

Issue is too many variations of the query...

Is it problem doing OR if the data is in two different tables? Anyway to speed them up?.

Thanks.

System - mysql apache2 php5 ubuntu - amazon aws.

Explain
[enter link description here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/26208095@N07/5738438708/sizes/l/in/photostream/)

**SOLVED IT BY**

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(movie_id)
FROM se_movies LEFT JOIN se_users ON se_movies.movie_user_id=se_users.user_id
INNER JOIN
( SELECT tag_object_id AS movieid FROM se_movie_contenttags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog')
UNION
SELECT tag_object_id AS movieid FROM se_movie_descriptiontags WHERE tag_name IN ('dog')
UNION
SELECT s1.movie_id AS movieid FROM se_movies as s1 WHERE s1.movie_title LIKE '%dog%'
UNION
SELECT s2.movie_id AS movieid FROM se_movies as s2 WHERE s2.movie_desc LIKE '%dog%'
)
AS tagobjects ON se_movies.movie_id=tagobjects.movieid

.5sec

Comment: Please let us know which indexes you have on your tables - and also attach the output of EXPLAIN SELECT ... to your question.

Comment: Is it intentional that the term after the OR clause in your slow query is not bracketed with other clauses?  You currently effectively have (A AND B AND C AND D) OR E, that is - if the RHS of the OR clause is true, the ANDs don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If `se_movie_descriptiontags` and `se_movie_contenttags` contain pairs of `(movie_id, tag)` and you want to include all movies that have certain tags, I would replace the `tagobjects` in-line view with:

```
SELECT `tag_object_id` AS `uid` FROM `se_movie_descriptiontags`
WHERE `tag_name` IN ('dog')
UNION
SELECT `tag_object_id` FROM `se_movie_contenttags`
WHERE `tag_name` IN ('dog')
```

This query will return the movie ids that have the tag 'dog' in any or both `se_movie_descriptiontags` and `se_movie_contenttags` tables. And then you can get rid of `OR ((cid IS NOT NULL OR did IS NOT NULL) AND uid IS NOT NULL)` on the main query.

The final full query would be:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(movie_id)
FROM
    se_movies LEFT JOIN
    se_users ON se_movies.movie_user_id=se_users.user_id INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT `tag_object_id` AS `uid` FROM `se_movie_descriptiontags`
        WHERE `tag_name` IN ('dog')
        UNION
        SELECT `tag_object_id` FROM `se_movie_contenttags`
        WHERE `tag_name` IN ('dog')
    ) AS tagobjects ON se_movies.movie_id=tagobjects.uid
WHERE (se_movies.movie_title LIKE '%dog%')
```

Also, note that `(se_movies.movie_title LIKE '%dog%')` alone is a performance killer, because it can't be optimized by using an index on the `movie_title` column, and will certainly cause a table scan.  This is mainly due to the fact that the condition starts with a wildcard.  For this type of scenario I would suggest looking into full-text search capabilities of MySQL.

Comment: Idea is allowing the logic in where class not in JOIN. I basically create a temp table for that keyword with desc flag, content flag , so i can do in future  do this . 1. content  or desc or title. 2. ( content and desc ) or title 3. content and title ..etc

Comment: In that case I think NoSQL is better suited for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying title or desc tags or content tags. I know that inner join optiion in that keyowrd is already in tags and then u search additional in that case u still have to use tagobjects.uid=null. I only want to understand the OR issue in that searching main table and join table values... it seems like it is repeating table scan many times...

Comment: i think i solved it , atleast it is better than before...can do Title or desc or  content.